# Sort arrays and hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have bunch of data:

```
[{"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"9"}]
{"id"=>"27"}
{"id"=>"5"}
{"id"=>"11"}
[{"id"=>"9"}, {"id"=>"23"}, {"id"=>"11"}, {"id"=>"19"}, {"id"=>"7"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"25"}, {"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"15"}, {"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"21"}, {"id"=>"17"}, {"id"=>"31"}]
{"id"=>"17"}
{"id"=>"13"}
[{"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"7"}, {"id"=>"5"}]
[{"id"=>"9"}, {"id"=>"11"}, {"id"=>"19"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"25"}, {"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"15"}, {"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"21"}, {"id"=>"17"}]
[{"id"=>"9"}, {"id"=>"3"}]
[{"id"=>"21"}, {"id"=>"11"}, {"id"=>"7"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"25"}]
{"id"=>"5"}
[{"id"=>"25"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"21"}]
{"id"=>"3"}
{"id"=>"11"}
[{"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"33"}, {"id"=>"7"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"37"}, {"id"=>"31"}]
[{"id"=>"13"}, {"id"=>"7"}, {"id"=>"5"}, {"id"=>"21"}]
```

Is any way to sort it to get:

```
arrays = all_arrays_here
hashes = all_hashes_here
```

All these are inside an Array.

Comment: Are those within an array?

Comment: Are all these data stored inside a larger array? Or some Enumerable class?

Comment: You need to supply valid data. As is, it's not valid and Ruby will choke if we try to use it. Please don't ask us to modify it until it is valid, because we can guess wrong resulting in an invalid answer. Also, you shouldn't ever receive a mix of data like that, so it makes me think there's something weird in the code generating it, or, this is [an XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're asking about one thing but really need to ask about another.

Comment: In future, please pare down your examples to the minimum required to make your point. If I understand your question correctly, this would have been sufficient: `arr = [[{"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"9"}], 
{"id"=>"27"}, {"id"=>"5"}, [{"id"=>"9"}, {"id"=>"23"}]]` or (better, imo): `arr = [[1,2], {"id"=>"27"}, {"id"=>"5"}, [3,4]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BroiSatse did the same thing first, but I think it's important to be able to see what Ruby does....

Consider this:

```
foo = [[1], {a: 2}, %w[3 4], {b: 5, c: 6}].group_by{ |e| e.class }
foo # => {Array=>[[1], ["3", "4"]], Hash=>[{:a=>2}, {:b=>5, :c=>6}]}
```

Ruby's built-in [`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is made for just this sort of problem.

Building on that:

```
arrays, hashes = foo.values_at(Array, Hash)

arrays # => [[1], ["3", "4"]]
hashes # => [{:a=>2}, {:b=>5, :c=>6}]
```

[`values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) retrieves the values from a hash (in this case) in the order specified.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this data is in some kind of enumerable object you can do:

```
arrays, hashes = data.group_by(&:class).values_at(Array, Hash)
```

However it feels wrong. Most likely you rather need to wrap each hash within its own array (so you can later to double iteration). If this is the case:

```
data.map! {|array_or_hash| Array.wrap(array_or_hash)}
```

Comment: ...if that's the latter, wouldn't plain `flatten` do? The question has been edited and yes, elements are stored in array.

Comment: @D-side - plain flatten would give us one single array with hashes - I am pretty sure those surrounding arrays means sth, like anonymous user groups. Flatting it would cost us some of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
  [{"id"=>"3"}, {"id"=>"9"}],
  {"id"=>"27"},
  {"id"=>"5"},
  {"id"=>"11"},
  [{"id"=>"9"}, {"id"=>"23"}, {"id"=>"11"}],
  {"id"=>"17"}
]

arrays, hashes = a.inject([[], []]) do |accum, item|
  item.is_a?(Array) ? accum[0] << item : accum[1] << item
  accum
end
```

Thus you have arrays and hashes separated from the variable a

Edit: Prefer @BroiSatse's solution to this.